# jstl problem : 2 last scriptlet to remove from my jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, scriptlet

I use a code that works fine but here's the last scriptlets in my jsp :

```
<%  List listMillesime= MultiMillesimeFactory.getInstance().getListMillesimeActif();
    pageContext.setAttribute("listMillesime",listMillesime);
    %>
...
<c:forEach var="millesime" items="${listMillesime}">
...
</c:forEach>
```

Here is the factory declaration :

```
public class MultiMillesimeFactory {

    private static MultiMillesime multiMillesime;

    private MultiMillesimeFactory(){
    }

    public static MultiMillesime getInstance() {
        if (multiMillesime == null) {
            multiMillesime = new MultiMillesime();
        }
        return multiMillesime;
    }
}
```

Multimillesime is a standard class with a method `getListMillesimeActif` returning a list. Declaration :

```
public class MultiMillesime {
...
   public List getListMillesimeActif() throws Exception {
     List _l = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList());
...
     return _l;
   }
}
```

c:for each works fine on list and enum but here the problem comes from the use of the getInstance, I've tried MultiMillesimeFactory.Instance.ListMillesimeActif without success.

And the last scriptlet is :

```
<a href='<%=request.getContextPath() %>
```

I'm not sure that both of these are removable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the `<%=request.getContextPath() %>` scriptlet with a JSTL tag:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
```

It is not uncommon to see something like this, either:

```
<c:set var="ctx" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
...
<a href="${ctx}" />
```

As for the issue with the `MultiMillesimeFactory`: it looks like that's a class in your codebase, and we can't magically debug that issue for you. It doesn't sound like a JSP problem.

What does "tried MultiMillesimeFactory.Instance.ListMillesimeActif without success" mean?

---

**Edit:** re: your comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but I'd guess the problem is that you need to use the fully qualified class name of `MultiMillesimeFactory` to look it up properly. However, you really should avoid using scriptlets as much as possible. Instead, use a proper servlet to inject the `ListMillesimeActif` into the request, like this:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet implements Servlet
{
    //...

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        //...
        List listMillesime = MultiMillesimeFactory.getInstance().getListMillesimeActif();
        request.setAttribute("millesime", listMillesime);
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: tried MultiMillesimeFactory.Instance.ListMillesimeActif without success : It means that usually jstl "find" the method which looks like a getter for an attribute or a pseudo attribute. Indeed I'm about 95% sure that  A.ListMillesimeActif find the A.getListMillesimeActif() method, even if ListMillesimeActif isn't an attribute of A class but just a method. I've tried the same for getInstance and I think that's the key of my problem.

Comment: @jayjay: see my edit. I'm still not clear on exactly what is "not successful" - do you get a compiler error? NullPointerException? etc.

Comment: no an empty list in my jsp, but your solution with that list in parameter must be good. I 'll try it then close this subject